# WCF MessageHeader Won't Write Namespace

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I have this code which for some reason is not writing the name or namespace or the attributes

```
public class MultiSpeakHeader : MessageHeader
{
    protected override void OnWriteHeaderContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion messageVersion)
    {
        writer.WriteAttributeString("AppName", "A");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("AppVersion", "1");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("CSUnits", "feet");
    }

    public override string Name
    {
        get { return "MultiSpeakMsgHeader"; }
    }

    public override string Namespace
    {
        get { return "http://www.multispeak.org/Version_3.0"; }
    }
}
```

The result of instance of the class this is the following:

```
<MultiSpeakHeader xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/my.app" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

i need this:

```
<MultiSpeakMsgHeader xmlns="http://www.multispeak.org/Version_3.0" AppName="A" AppVersion="1" CSUnits="feet" />
```

Code using:

```
AddressHeader[] header = { AddressHeader.CreateAddressHeader(new MultiSpeakHeader()) };
```

Comment: I presume this is for WCF?

Comment: It's good to put [tag:wcf] in the tags if you're working with WCF.

Comment: anyone, anyone out there?

Comment: I've never used this, but maybe try OnWriteStartHeader. Try to write the name.

Comment: I'm seeing this same problem. Breakpoint in OnWriteHeaderContents isn't even being hit... so freaking frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to add attribute but the root node needs to have prefix. I tried to avoid it but unsuccessful.

```
writer.WriteXmlnsAttribute("test", this.Namespace);
writer.WriteAttributeString("AppName", "A");
writer.WriteAttributeString("AppVersion", "1");
writer.WriteAttributeString("CSUnits", "feet");
```